# Jersey 2 + Spring 4 without web.xml/applicationContext.xml

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, jersey, jersey-2.0

I have 2 Maven projects:

- project1 that contains my entities/services/DAOs, with a Java Spring (4.2.4) config (no XML)
- project2 that is my RESTful API using Jersey (2.22.1), that contains the resources (controllers), Java configuration (extending `ResourceConfig`, no web.xml)

I would like to inject my services in my Jersey resources, here is what I did:

1. I added the Maven dependency to project1 in project2
2. I added the dependency jersey-spring3 to project2

I didn't change anything in my Jersey config class.

I run jetty (Maven plugin, no `public static void main` or any class to run the server).
First attempt: applicationContext.xml was required.
Second attempt: after adding an empty applicationContext.xml (to project2), my services are not found.
Third attempt: after adding `<context:component-scan base-package="com.xxx.project1"/>` to applicationContext.xml (package where my project1 Java Spring config lives), services are injected.

**My question is how to get rid of the applicationContext.xml file?**
I would like my Spring config from project1 to be detected automatically...

Some code:
The Spring configuration

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.xxx.project1.service")
public class SpringConfig {

}
```

The Jersey configuration

```
@ApplicationPath("/v1")
public class Application extends ResourceConfig {

    public Application() {
        packages("com.xxx.project2.filter",
        "com.xxx.project2.resource");
        register(RolesAllowedDynamicFeature.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a Spring [`WebApplicationInitializer`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32550131/2587435) to bootstrap the Spring components. You can see an example in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32357991/2587435).

Comment: Thanks, I'll let you know as soon as I test it.